# GPU multiprocessing for VGG19 large scale predictions

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I'm using the VGG19 for transfer learning.

I have a code that already correctly runs VGG19 predictions for a set of images. It first reads the image content and then it expands the shape and preprocess the input array for the VGG19. After that, the prediction is called and the wanted output is a feature tensor. Summary code below.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import keras
from PIL import Image
from tensorflow.keras.applications import VGG19
from tensorflow.keras.applications.vgg19 import preprocess_input
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image as kimage

model = VGG19(include_top=False, weights='imagenet', input_shape=(224, 224, 3))

img = Image.open('img.jpg')
img_array = kimage.img_to_array(img)
x = np.expand_dims(img_array, axis=0)
xs = preprocess_input(x)
features = model.predict(xs)
```

Thing is, I need to run this in a very large scale, and although I do have 4 GPU's available on the machine, the code as it is only uses one GPU (I already checked - the GPU:0). So my question is, how do I make the above code run in parallel for all the 4 available GPU's so I can use all the machine potential?

I already tried `tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy` and I'll try to summarize the code below. Although it shows the 4 GPU's processing at the same time, only the first GPU has all of its capacity being used while the other 3 only show at a rate of 5-10%, and when I time both codes for a medium sized sample of images (1k images), the first code (with only one GPU running) performs better. Am I doing something wrong?

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import keras
from PIL import Image
from tensorflow.keras.applications import VGG19
from tensorflow.keras.applications.vgg19 import preprocess_input
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image as kimage

model = VGG19(include_top=False, weights='imagenet', input_shape=(224, 224, 3))

strategy = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy()
print('Number of devices: {}'.format(strategy.num_replicas_in_sync))

with strategy.scope():
    img = Image.open('img.jpg')
    img_array = kimage.img_to_array(img)
    x = np.expand_dims(img_array, axis=0)
    xs = preprocess_input(x)
    features = model.predict(xs)
```

(I summarized the code for just one image only to illustrate it, but I'm running both codes with an array of images inside of a for loop).

Comment: I am not sure what your question is here, you already have code to use mutliple GPUs, but you are somehow expecting for all GPUs to be completely used, but that won't happen until you put some real calculation on it, also consider how the batch size plays into this.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy As I said I did run the code with a medium sized sample of images and even though it didn't use all of the GPUs capacity, at least I expected it to run faster than the one without multiprocessing, which didn't happen.. but can you give more clarification about the batch size please?

Comment: Increase the batch size in model.predict, the default is 32.